# Online machine learning tutorial

Tags: machine-learning, education, beginner

Does anyone know some good tutorials on online machine learning technics?
I.e. how it can be used in real-time environments, what are key differences compared to normal machine learning methods etc.

UPD: Thank you everyone for answers, by "online" I mean methods which can be trained in a real-time mode, based on a new inputs one by one.

Comment: Could you clarify key aspects of "online" that you are interested in? Do you have a specific form for the data, or any options to pre-train your algorithm before the online part?

Comment: do you mean to analyze datastreams?

Answer (score 5):

1. There is a very nice library of online machine learning algorithms from a group at NTU, called [`LIBOL`](http://libol.stevenhoi.org/). This would be a very good place to start experimenting with the algorithms.
   The [accompanying user guide](http://libol.stevenhoi.org/LIBOL_manual.pdf), and [associated JMLR publication](http://jmlr.org/papers/v15/hoi14a.html) are very nice introductions to the basic algorithms in this field.
2. Avrim Blum has an older and more technical [survey paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/Papers/survey.pdf) on online learning algorithms.

Comment: The first two links are dead.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of online tutorial. Especially in youtube, but if you will want accurate website you can see from here http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~shai/icml08tutorial/ or http://cs229.stanford.edu/materials.html. you can visit them now.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Can you expand on the content in this link that you think is relevant?

Answer (score 1):

You can see if you can mix Spark streaming (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html) and Spark ML Library (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/mllib-guide.html).

Spark Streaming permits to process live data streams and Spark ML Library is a Machine Learning Library for Spark. So maybe you can do something good!

But this is a very interesting subject, I am working on it. It can be good to create a Google Community on it (https://plus.google.com/communities)?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty on youtube and here's a famous one by Andrew Ng from coursea: https://www.coursera.org/course/ml

Comment: I am not 100% convinced by the topics on that course. For example, are SVMs actually of practical use these days? You never see a winning Kaggle entry that used SVMs as the main part.

Comment: I think OP's question is specifically about *online* techniques - i.e. where system is expected to learn at least partially "on the job". Not *online tutorials*

Comment: I agree with @NeilSlater since the OP mentioned "compared to normal machine learning methods".

Comment: lol, "online" is ambiguous